# British citizen, why does my South-African wife need a visa to visit me in the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, uk-citizens, south-america

My wife is South African, why does she need a visa to visit me in the UK?         I am English, born and bred.

Comment: What answer are you expecting other than "because the law says she does"?

Answer (score 10):

It's a valid question (assuming your interest is genuine).

South African nationals were non-visa nationals up to 2012, meaning they could arrive and seek leave to enter just like Australians, Canadians, and so on.  But starting in about 2006, the Home Office determined that there were grave performance issues and asked Parliament to [add South Africa to the visa national list](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423477/20150424_mmigration_rules_app_v_final_v2.pdf).

[image]
Source: [UK Home Office on Twitter](https://twitter.com/ukhomeoffice/status/352408433506533377)

South African nationals did not 'lead the way' in terms of abuse, but they always occupied a slot in the top 10.  In addition to performance problems, there were lots of cases of [disputed nationality and specious human rights claims](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/257467/natinality-doubtful-disputed.pdf) that set South Africa apart from the rest of the affluent Commonwealth.  So Parliament changed South Africa's status.  It was done through [orders in council](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_in_Council) so finding the precise debate(s) will be difficult, if even  possible.

That answers your question.  The corollary to your question is 'when will they change it back?'  Based upon the results of yesterday's election, I think it's safe to assume it will not get changed back until some time after 2020.  Based upon its variegated history, they will not be in a hurry to make it happen.

Finally, you mentioned that you are 'English born and bred'.  So you would be in a position to know that you can take up the matter with [your constituency office](http://www.ukpolitical.info/Finder.htm) and advocate that they change the rule sooner.

Comment: Can you clarify what "performance problems" means in this context?

Comment: @user568458 Overstay, illegal working, WHM abuse (before the WHM programme was discontinued altogether), marriage abuse, etc. It's a catch-all phrase covering all the things that get the authorities upset.

Comment: Thanks. What's WHM in this context? Something to do with working holidays? All the search results I get are for "Web host manager"...

Comment: @user568458, Working Holiday Maker, a Commonwealth thing that was curtailed a long time ago.

Comment: I withdraw my comment! Having just visited SA, I can understand why it's in the top 10. I'll delete my comments.

Comment: @mkennedy, if you've got some insight, make an answer. The OP is (apparently) waiting for something.  You can write your ideas down

Comment: Nothing beyond the economy is running a few years behind the US, so the crash in 2008 in the US, hit them later, and they're still recovering. Opportunities for everyone are limited.